# wakanda.getCatalog() returns an error if describe permissions are missing on one of the datastore classes

Tags: wakanda

the method `getCatalog()` of the wakanda javascript client returns the following error, if no data class array is passed to the method and one of the describe permissions in the model is missing for the current user (this is most likely the case).

**Error:**

```
{
  "__ERROR": [
    {
      "message": "No permission to describe the User datastore class",
      "componentSignature": "dbmg",
      "errCode": 1609
    }
  ]
}
```

What is considered best practice to use the `getCatalog()` method? Is it best to pass the data class needed to the `getCatalog()` method on every call made to the server?

**Example of angular company service:**

```
@Injectable()
export class CompanyService {

  constructor(private wakandaService: WakandaService,
              private exceptionService: ExceptionService) {
  }

  getCompanyList(): any {
    return this.wakandaService.getCatalog(['Company'])
    .then(data => {
      return data.UserProfile.getProfile();
    })
    .then(data => {      
      return data;
    })
    .catch(error => this.exceptionService.error(error));
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

**DataModel**

[image: DataModel]

**Permissions**

Role & User data class need "Admin" permissions.
UserProfile data class needs "User" permissions and is extended from the User data class.

**Error**

When logged in as User and call `getCatalog(['UserProfile'])` the error *"Needed Role dataClass is not present on catalog"* is returned. -> Is this correct? Why is the same thing through the REST API working?

http://localhost:8081/rest/$catalog/UserProfile works just fine.

When logged in as User and call `getCatalog(['UserProfile', 'Role'])` the error *"No permission to describe the Role datastore class"* is returned. -> OK

Answer (score 1):

Not sure yet to have all the details needed to perfectly answer you (not sure about how your model is defined (User, UserProfile..) 
. But however here's how it works.
When passing a Dataclass in the getCatalog() method it retrieves only the specified dataclass.

*Attention* If your dataclasses are linked (relation <> ) you must add the related dataclasses (the expand is automatically needed )

You should be able to make it work by simply writing return `this.wakandaService.getCatalog(['Company', 'User'])`

Of course you can also pass an empty array to get the whole catalog
`this.wakandaService.getCatalog()`

Could you confirm me that it solves your issue ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Hi Fred, i did an update on my post trying to be a bit more spcific. Hope you understand what I'm trying to explain.

Answer (score 1):

Really sorry, I totally missed the fact you had updated your post.
Thanks for the update btw, it's now perfectly clear.
Well  I made a quick solution to try reproducing yr issue.
(it's not exactly the same but it helped)

Several points :

- We have recently updated the getCatalog method to make it more equal to the REST API. In our current `DEV` version, when you have an Extended Dataclass and a related Dataclass you have to add in the getCatalog all the dataclasses
  In your case it would be :

`getCatalog(['UserProfile', 'Role', User])` 
When doing this you are able

```
wakClient.getCatalog(['UserProfile', 'User', 'Role']).then(function (ds) {
  console.log(ds);
  ds.UserProfile.query().then(function (result) 
      {
     console.log(result) 
            }
     )      
    });
```

And it works

- However, I'de done this quick test with `read Permissions` and not describe as we currently have a bug on the `describe` permission.
  As soon as we have fix it, i'll redo the same test with describe permissions and get back to you asap.